# Finding out Rejected Addresses in Cc and Bcc also - how to?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I can find out rejected addresses within swiftmailer from the ->setTo(array(. With the following code:

```
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance( ... );
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance( ... )
->setFrom( ... )
->setTo(array(
'receiver@bad-domain.org' => 'Receiver Name',
'other@domain.org' => 'A name',
'other-receiver@bad-domain.org' => 'Other Name'
))
->setBody( ... )
;

// Pass a variable name to the send() method
if (!$mailer->send($message, $failures))
{
echo "Failures:";
print_r($failures);
}

/*
Failures:
Array (
0 => receiver@bad-domain.org,
1 => other-receiver@bad-domain.org
)
*/
```

Now I want to find out rejected addresses from Cc and Bcc fields too. How can I add similar code? Is there a tutorial or a workaround? There is no example in the swiftmailer tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try-catch` block where you set the to, cc, and bcc email addresses.

From [the manual](http://swiftmailer.org/pdf/Swiftmailer.pdf):

> If you add recipients automatically based on a data source that may
>   contain invalid email addresses, you can prevent possible exceptions
>   by validating the addresses using `Swift_Validate::email($email)` and
>   only adding addresses that validate. Another way would be to wrap your
>   `setTo()`, `setCc()` and `setBcc()` calls in a try-catch block and handle
>   the `Swift_RfcComplianceException` in the catch block.

So you can use the `try-catch` on `$message` object:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$emails = array(
    'receiver@bad-domain.org' => 'Receiver Name',
    'other@domain.org' => 'A name',
    'other-receiver@bad-domain.org' => 'Other Name'
);
// loop through emails and set the individually to catch exceptions
foreach($emails as $email => $name)
{
    try {
        $message->setTo(array($email => $name));
    } catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {
        echo "The email ".$email." seems invalid";
    }
}
// And do the same thing with cc and bcc emails
$ccEmails = array(
    'receiver@ccemail.org' => 'CC Receiver Name'
);
foreach($ccEmails as $email => $name)
{
    try {
        $message->setCc(array($email => $name));
    } catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {
        echo "The email ".$email." seems invalid";
    }
}
```

You could set the failures to a variable if you depending on how you want to handle them.

**Edit:** If you have an array of users with separate first and last names you can user the below:

```
$users = array(
    array('email' => 'receiver@bad-domain.org', 'first' => 'Receiver', 'last' => 'Name'),
    array('email' => 'other@domain.org', 'first' => 'A', 'last' => 'name'),
    array('email' => 'other-receiver@bad-domain.org', 'first' => 'Other', 'last' => 'Name')
);
// loop through users and set the individually to catch exceptions
foreach($users as $user)
{
    try {
        $message->setTo(array($user['email'] => $user['first'].' '.$user['last']));
    } catch(Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {
        echo "The email ".$user['email']." seems invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for Your quick answer. I'll try the catch-Method. I want to display all rejected receivers include the Cc and Bcc to correct them into my database. By the way - could ich split the receiver-array into a form like: emailadress - firstname - secondname  ? Cause the names in my DB are splittet in first-and secondnames